# Java Selenium Mouse movement in Decentraland

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, decentraland

I'm trying to automate the process of moving in Decentraland (a metaverse https://decentraland.org/). After I automated the process of signing up and everything, I jump into the land but when using `actions.moveToElement(element, x, y);`, no error shows but it won't move the screen of Decentraland for some reason.

Here's the code

```
package com.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public final class App {
    /**
     * Says hello to the world.
     * @param args The arguments of the program.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://play.decentraland.org/?position=45%2C19&realm=fenrir-amber");

        Dimension targetSize = new Dimension(800, 600);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(targetSize);

        sleep(1);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"eth-login-confirmation-wrapper\"]/button[2]")).click();

        sleep(30);

        // avatar section
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"#canvas\"]"));
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 333, 210).click().perform();
        
        // create profile section
        actions = new Actions(driver);
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"#canvas\"]"));
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 130, -53).click().perform();
        new Actions(driver).sendKeys("a").perform();
        actions.moveToElement(element, 138, 103).click().perform();

        // tos section
        actions = new Actions(driver);
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"#canvas\"]"));
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 283, -99).clickAndHold().perform();
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 283, 58).release().perform();
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 140, 97).click().perform();

        // click got it button in land
        // 0, 166
        actions = new Actions(driver);
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"#canvas\"]"));
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 0, 166).click().perform();

        // pan shot
        actions = new Actions(driver);
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"#canvas\"]"));
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
        sleep(5);
        actions.moveToElement(element).doubleClick().perform();
        sleep(5);
        for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
            actions.moveToElement(element, 0, 10 * i).click().perform();
        }
    }

    public static void sleep(int seconds)  {
        try {
            internalSleep(seconds);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void internalSleep(int seconds) throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
        Thread.sleep((long)seconds * 1000);
    }

    public static void print(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Change `actions.moveToElement(element, 333, 210).click().perform();` to        `actions.moveToElement(element, 333, 210).build().perform();`

Comment: That works perfectly fine. Its the code in the for loop not moving the view of the camera in decentraland

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Not yet lol >.<